# How should I set a default value for a delegate?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, delegation

I have a class with a `delegate` property that conforms to a protocol:

**MyClass.h**

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyProtocol> delegate;

@end
```

I'd like to set a default value for the `delegate` property, much like a `UITableViewController` would do.

Consider the following:

**MyClass.m**

```
@interface MyClass ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) id<MyProtocol> defaultDelegate;

@end


@implementation MyClass

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _defaultDelegate = // something conforming to MyProtocol
        _delegate = _defaultDelegate;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Are there any concerns with this approach, or can it be improved in any way?

---

### Update #1

What about the following?

The property isn't called `delegate`, but something like `colorPalette` or `fontFamilies` which needs a default value.

Everything in the protocol is `@required`.

At runtime the value of the property may be set to something else (an instance of another class that conforms to the protocol).

---

### Update #2

I'm trying to encapsulate the (default) behavior.

Consider that there are 3 classes conforming to the protocol - initially I might want to use all of the values from the first. Tomorrow I might choose that the second is a better default. Additionally, the user may set a preference at runtime which could use any of the 3.

Comment: `nil` because sending message to `nil` is nop

Comment: Also, convention is that default value of delegate should be nil. Therefore, everywhere you are calling a method on the delegate, make sure it behaves properly.

Comment: If setting the delegate value is not optional, just assert on protocol value being nil.

Comment: delegates are usually weak (assign) references and "NOT" strong (retain). it's default is nil. you can implement logic in the place where you dont have the delegate set.

Answer (score 1):

The default value should be nil. There is no reason to give it a value. When all your other classes use it, the expected behavior is that full implementation of the delegate is needed. When you start adding default values you're defeating the whole point.

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate should be nil by default. However, to achieve the default values like UITableView, your class should check if the delegate responds to each optional delegate method using [respondsToSelector:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/respondsToSelector%3a) (if the delegate is nil, it will respond false). If the delegate doesn't respond, then you use a default value. You don't need to setup a "default delegate" to do that.

Your code would look something like this:

```
NSString *stringValue = nil;
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(getStringValue)]) {
     stringValue = [self.delegate getStringValue];
}
else {
    stringValue = @"Default value";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for that kind of implementation:

```
if (delegate == nil) {
    // default behavior
} else {
    [delegate methodToCallWithParameters:...];
}
```

If your property has to implement a protocol, that's a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a combination of responses, it sounds like I should do this:

```
@interface MyClass ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) id<MyProtocol> currentColorPalette;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<MyProtocol> defaultColorPalette;

@end


@implementation MyClass

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _defaultColorPalette = [[SomeClassConformingToProtocol alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setColorPalette:(id<MyProtocol>)colorPalette
{
    _colorPalette = colorPalette;
    _currentColorPalette = _colorPalette;
}

- (id<MyProtocol>)currentColorPalette
{
    id<MyProtocol> colorPalette = nil;

    if (self.currentColorPalette == nil) {
        colorPalette = self.defaultColorPalette;
    }
    else {
        colorPalette = self.currentColorPalette;
    }

    return colorPalette;
}


#pragma mark - MyProtocol

- (void)doSomethingWithCurrentColorPalette
{
    [self.currentColorPalette someDelegateMethod];
}

@end
```